# Bring absolutely positioned element back into flow of flexbox parent element

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm working on a layout with a navigation and nested subnav. The bottom of the subnav needs to align to the bottom of the parent element. To save you some reading, the easiest way to describe this is to just point to this CodePen that I made.

http://codepen.io/freshyill/pen/drxaJ

[image: Screenshot]

**Now, to actually explain what I'm trying to do:**

- The navigation (the subnav, specifically), needs to align to the bottom of the parent.
- The parent element is `display: flex` and `justify-content: flex-end`, so the navigation will align to the bottom.
- The primary nav is horizontal and `position: relative`.
- The subnav is also horizontal and `position: absolute` below the nav.
- The search area's height is unknown and doesn't need to align to the top of the parent

The problem is that since the subnav is `position: absolute`, the primary nav, not the subnav is actually at the bottom, and the subnav is outside the parent.

**A few more things…**

- I will have very little control over the markup of the nav lists.
- I could solve this by setting a height on the subnav and giving the primary nav a bottom margin of the same value. I'm trying to avoid this.
- The real subnav will roll over to display other subnavs
- I'm willing to consider other solutions to moving the subnav below the nav.

Comment: will the subnav appear on hover?

Comment: PLease post the HTML and CSS from your Codepen in your question. It might not appear particularly useful now, but if the 'pen you linked is deleted or goes missing, your question becomes useless to future visitors looking for an answer

Answer (score 2):

imho there's no need for position absolute, you can use negative margins instead.

for example, if the submenu is the one under the third button, to reset its left-offset, just do `margin-left:-200%`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rupco3wh/

here's the solution key:

```
ul.navlist > li > ul.subnav
{
    width:400%;
}

ul.navlist > li:nth-child(2) > ul.subnav
{
    margin-left:-100%;
}

ul.navlist > li:nth-child(3) > ul.subnav
{
    margin-left:-200%;
}

ul.navlist > li:nth-child(4) > ul.subnav
{
    margin-left:-300%;
}
```

hope it fits your needs